# How to make jenkins move to the next stage if its "terminal" has been blocked?

Tags: node.js, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to run http calls for testing a live web api that's going to run in the jenkins machine.

This is the pipeline script that's been used.

```
stage 'build'
    node {
        git url: 'https://github.com/juliomarcos/sample-http-test-ci/'
        sh "npm install"
        sh "npm start"
    }
stage 'test'
    node {
        sh "npm test"
    }
```

But jenkins won't move to the **test** step. How can I run `npm test` after the web app has fully started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to start the web app with an & at the end so it will run in the background. i.e.

`npm start &`

You can try to redirect the output of npm start to a text file like this:

`npm start > output.txt &`

Then in the next step, loop until the "started" message is available, something like:

```
tail -f output.txt | while read LOGLINE
do
   [[ "${LOGLINE}" == *"listening on port"* ]] && pkill -P $$ tail
done
```

Code not tested :)

Comment: If I do that, how can I be certain that the test will only start after the app has finished its starting procedure?

Comment: Julio Rodrigues How did you fix this one? I'm having a similar issue